# Groovy map coercion access class level variable in closure

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, metaprogramming

I am trying to override a complex method in a builder for some unit testing. This is a web service request builder so the builder class has an instance variable of the request type named `request`.

so I am trying to do this:

```
def mockBuilder = [complexMethod:{request.setAnAttribute(it)}] as MyBuilder
```

When I run my unit test I get a method missing exception

```
No such property: request for class:com.xx.etc.MyBuilderTest
```

I have tried `this.request` and setting the `resolveStrategy` to go to the `delegate` first (which I thought would be the class `MyBuilder` but that didn't work).

I know when this `mockBuilder` is being instantiated it is calling the default constructor of `MyBuilder` (which initializes the class's `request` variable) so I imagine somewhere the `request` variable is available but I have had trouble finding it.

Comment: I was able to get around this by making a private static inner class in my test and extending my builder.In this new class I implemented the complex method how I wanted it to be in the closure. When I created a new instance of the private mock builder and used it - it worked.

Comment: You would need to show the way `complexMethod` is called in order to get help with the mocking of it.

Comment: its not so much the method mocking that I need help with the method takes one parameter which is a string and thats what the closure is setting - its accessing the class instance variable named request. From the error message the closure is looking to MyBuilderTest for the variable request which doesn't exist. I wonder why and if I could point the closure to look in the MyBuilderInstance it is 'resembling' for the request variable (since its an instance variable of MyBuilder)